# Testing web service in JDeveloper 12c

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, parameters, jdeveloper

I have made very simple web service using **JDeveloper 12c**.
I have a class named Person:

```
package testapp;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;    
    public Person() {super();}    
    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) this.firstname=firstname;this.lastname=lastname;}
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {this.firstname = firstname;}
    public String getFirstname() {return firstname;}
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {this.lastname = lastname;}
    public String getLastname() {return lastname;}
}
```

...and a class PersonService:

```
package testapp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.*;
public class PersonService {
    private List<Person> persons;
    public PersonService() {
        super();
        this.persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot find Oracle driver!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("STATUS: Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(/* my database connection parameters */);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Connection Failed! Check output console!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("STATUS: Connection established.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Failed to establish connection!");
        }
        try {
            String selectSQL = "/* select first and last name from database */";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                this.persons.add(/* Get data from database and make new Person */);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (preparedStatement != null) {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Something is seriously wrong...");
            }
        }
    }
    public List<Person> getPersons() {return this.persons;}
    public void addPerson(String firstname, String lastname) {
        if (firstname != null && lastname != null) {
            System.out.println("Hello, "+firstname+" "+lastname+"!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: First name or last name is null!");
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed [this tutorial](http://multikoop.blogspot.com/2013/08/jdeveloper-12c-create-restful-service.html) to make a web service and to test it. I chose application/xml and application/json type of parameters. Finally, my addPerson method looks like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(value = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
@Path("/person")
public void addPerson(@FormParam("firstname") String firstname, @FormParam("lastname") String lastname) {
    if ((firstname != null) && (lastname != null)) {
        System.out.println("Hello, "+firstname+" "+lastname+"!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: First name or last name is null!");
    }
}
```

I'm able to test my GET method (getPersons), and I get a nice looking response. But I have no idea how to test POST method (addPerson), i.e. I don't know how to supply the parameters. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried clicking on the green plus sign (Add header), then changing the header names to "firstname" and "lastname" and setting some values, but when I click "Send request", an error message appears (first name or last name is null).

What is the right way to enter some input parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormParam requires a form through which the parameters can be picked up. If you want to test this, in the service, change the parameter type to PathParam or QueryParam. This way, you can test it using the analyzer.
So, in case of QueryParam, your addPerson would look like:

public void addPerson(@QueryParam("firstname") String firstname, @QueryParam("lastname") String lastname) {
:
:
}

In analyzer, you can just append ?firstname=ABC&lastname=XYZ to the URL and send request.

Answer (score 1):

you have to give the firstname and lastname in the bar provided just above the Send request 
 button
in the following manner

firstname=vladmir&lastname=tonic

and then click send request button